# Query results to new table object in F#

Tags: f#, dataframe

Short question.

I have just recently performed my first successful query in F#. I now want to be able to refer to the results and perform various computations on it. If I just assign the query to an object, "newData," it does not let me refer to the elements of this new data table (e.g. newData.Billed_Amount).

Is there a quick function like ToList() to make it so that I can work with this new data?

Here is some sample code:

```
let dc = new TypedDataContext()

let newData = query { for x in dc.MyData do
                      where (x.ID = "number of type string")
                      groupBy x.Code into g
                      let average = query { for x in g do
                                            averageBy x.Billed_Amt }
                      select (g, average) }

System.Console.WriteLine(newData)
```

I now want to, for example, calculate standard deviation within all the groups, but I noticed I cannot perform this computation within a query. This is where I would like to have the query results referable to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: `Seq.toList` ? Example code would make this question much easier to answer. Or maybe just the type of `newData`?

Comment: Done! Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
newData |> Seq.toList
```

The pipe operator `|>` applies the function on the right to the value on the left. You could put it into `newData` if you want it to be a list:

```
let newData = query { for x in dc.MyData do
                      ...
                      select (g, average) }
              |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: great! But I still cannot reference a column of my data... I imagine it is because of the grouping method I used... I think the only referable objects in the list I just created with your answer are the keys to the groups.

Comment: What's the type of `newData`?

Comment: I think I might post a separate question regarding this struggle of referencing columns of grouped data... In any case, this works great, thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what the type is. Looks like decimal, perhaps.

Comment: In the interpreter (fsi), if you just paste in the entire thing, it says something along the lines `val newData : type = ...`.

Comment: I am using LINQPad, so I do not have an interpreter or get output like that, from the looks of it. One of the column names is Billed_Amt. When I try this line of code: let sd = newData.Billed_Amt.StandardDeviation(), I get the error that "constructor or member 'Billed_Amt' is not defined." I also tried doing newData.g.Billed-Amt. Same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Because `IQueryable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, you can use functions in the `Seq` module such as `toList` and `toArray`.

```
open System.Linq //for AsQueryable extension method

let q s =
  query {
    for x in s do
    where (x > 1)
    select x
  }

q ([1; 2].AsQueryable()) |> Seq.toList //[2]
```

Comment: What does the [1; 2] refer to here? Is that just an example of data?